# Constraining monotonicity in the loss function during training

Tags: python, ai, neural-network, tensorflow

I have a neural network that I am training on a loss function composed of two terms (i.e. `loss = loss1 + loss2`). Ideally, I would like for both `loss1` and `loss2` to simultaneously decrease. Although I am wondering, is there any way to ensure neither `loss1` nor `loss2` increase during training, i.e. while minimizing `loss` is the overall objective, to constrain just `loss1` to be monotonically decreasing?

Below I have written a simple arbitrary example whereby I construct and train a neural network on a loss function composed of two terms that are potentially competing. I simply use `L-BFGS` and `Adam` to perform this optimization. But to improve upon this code, are there any best known practices, methods, or optimizers for handling loss functions and trying to enforce a robust monotonicity constraint on constituent loss terms during training?

---

```
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf

end_it = 1000 #number of iterations
layers = [2, 20, 20, 20, 1]

#Generate training data
len_data = 10000
x_x = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.,len_data)])
x_y = np.array([np.linspace(0.,1.,len_data)]) 
y_true = np.array([np.linspace(-0.2,0.2,len_data)])

N_train = int(len_data)
idx = np.random.choice(len_data, N_train, replace=False)

x_train = x_x.T[idx,:]
y_train = x_y.T[idx,:] 
v1_train = y_true.T[idx,:] 

sample_batch_size = int(0.01*N_train)

np.random.seed(1234)
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
import logging
logging.getLogger('tensorflow').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)

class NeuralNet:
    def __init__(self, x, y, v1, layers):
        X = np.concatenate([x, y], 1)  
        self.lb = X.min(0)
        self.ub = X.max(0)
        self.X = X
        self.x = X[:,0:1]
        self.y = X[:,1:2] 
        self.v1 = v1 
        self.layers = layers 
        self.weights_v1, self.biases_v1 = self.initialize_NN(layers) 
        self.sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=False,
                                                     log_device_placement=False)) 
        self.x_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.x.shape[1]])
        self.y_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.y.shape[1]]) 
        self.v1_tf = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, self.v1.shape[1]])  
        self.v1_pred = self.net(self.x_tf, self.y_tf)
        self.loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v1_pred)) 
        self.loss2 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.v1_tf - self.v1_pred)) 
        self.loss = self.loss1 + self.loss2
        self.optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(self.loss,
                                                                var_list=self.weights_v1+self.biases_v1,
                                                                method = 'L-BFGS-B',
                                                                options = {'maxiter': 50,
                                                                           'maxfun': 50000,
                                                                           'maxcor': 50,
                                                                           'maxls': 50,
                                                                           'ftol' : 1.0 * np.finfo(float).eps})
        self.optimizer_Adam = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
        self.train_op_Adam_v1 = self.optimizer_Adam.minimize(self.loss, var_list=self.weights_v1+self.biases_v1) 
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()  
        self.sess.run(init)
    def initialize_NN(self, layers):
        weights = []
        biases = []
        num_layers = len(layers)
        for l in range(0,num_layers-1):
            W = self.xavier_init(size=[layers[l], layers[l+1]])
            b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,layers[l+1]], dtype=tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32)
            weights.append(W)
            biases.append(b) 
        return weights, biases
    def xavier_init(self, size):
        in_dim = size[0]
        out_dim = size[1]
        xavier_stddev = np.sqrt(2/(in_dim + out_dim)) 
        return tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([in_dim, out_dim], stddev=xavier_stddev), dtype=tf.float32)
    def neural_net(self, X, weights, biases):
        num_layers = len(weights) + 1
        H = 2.0*(X - self.lb)/(self.ub - self.lb) - 1.0
        for l in range(0,num_layers-2):
            W = weights[l]
            b = biases[l]
            H = tf.tanh(tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b))
        W = weights[-1]
        b = biases[-1]
        Y = tf.add(tf.matmul(H, W), b) 
        return Y
    def net(self, x, y): 
        v1_out = self.neural_net(tf.concat([x,y], 1), self.weights_v1, self.biases_v1)
        v1 = v1_out[:,0:1]
        return v1
    def callback(self, loss):
        global Nfeval
        print(str(Nfeval)+' - Loss in loop: %.3e' % (loss))
        Nfeval += 1
    def fetch_minibatch(self, x_in, y_in, v1_in, N_train_sample):  
        idx_batch = np.random.choice(len(x_in), N_train_sample, replace=False)
        x_batch = x_in[idx_batch,:]
        y_batch = y_in[idx_batch,:] 
        v1_batch = v1_in[idx_batch,:] 
        return x_batch, y_batch, v1_batch
    def train(self, end_it):
        it = 0
        while it < end_it: 
            x_res_batch, y_res_batch, v1_res_batch = self.fetch_minibatch(self.x, self.y, self.v1, sample_batch_size) # Fetch residual mini-batch
            tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x_res_batch, self.y_tf: y_res_batch,
                       self.v1_tf: v1_res_batch}
            self.sess.run(self.train_op_Adam_v1, tf_dict)
            self.optimizer.minimize(self.sess,
                                    feed_dict = tf_dict,
                                    fetches = [self.loss],
                                    loss_callback = self.callback) 
            it = it + 1
    def predict(self, x_star, y_star): 
        tf_dict = {self.x_tf: x_star, self.y_tf: y_star}
        v1_star = self.sess.run(self.v1_pred, tf_dict)  
        return v1_star

model = NeuralNet(x_train, y_train, v1_train, layers)
 
Nfeval = 1
model.train(end_it)
```

Comment: This goal would cause the search to stop at any local minima. It makes sense only for certain optimization problems where the local and global minimas are the same.

Comment: @GZ0 Yes, such a loss term is useful in only certain problems. But I wonder if such a loss term can even be encoded (e.g. in a classical feedforward neural network as I've encoded above)?

Comment: 1. Convergence of training is different from monotonically decreasing of training loss -- which is a much stronger condition. 2. Convergence is determined by both the optimization problem (i.e. the prediction and loss functions) and the optimizer you choose. 3. In your problem the overall loss function can be simplified to a regular square loss so it should not hard for the training to converge.

Comment: Correct, I don't disagree with these points in theory. But my question is regarding the practicality of implementing such a loss function in the TensorFlow code. Namely, the proposed loss function requires knowing losses from previous iterations during training (and therefore the state of the neural network in the past as well for it to be a trainable parameter, as far as I can tell). But is it possible to actually train on past loss functions in TensorFlow? If so, how can this actually be encoded in the example?

Comment: If that is really what you want, the training loop needs to be customized. You need to obtain the loss values after each training step and stop training once the monotonicity constraint is violated.

Comment: Yes, that can all be done. But there is an additional necessary step. Namely, I want the optimizer to not simply stop but to keep training (i.e. try updating weights) in such a way that the monotonicity constraint isn't broken. But the neural network (and, consequently, the optimizer) only trains its weights at the current iteration. The current weights are all it knows. The neural network does not contain any information about its weights from the past, but I believe this would be required for the optimizer I'm describing to work. To be able to do this in any way is the crux of my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple approaches you can try:

## Gradient projection

Let's say the total loss to minimize is `lossTotal = loss1 + loss2`. When computing the gradients of `lossTotal` wrt to `loss1` and `loss2`, you end up with `grads1` and `grads2` the gradients of your model wrt to `loss1` and `loss2`. You can project the gradients of one loss onto the other so that you can minimize a loss without affection the score of the other term. Here are some paper about it:

- [Continual Learning with Scaled Gradient Projection](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.01386)
- [Rethinking Gradient Projection Continual Learning: Stability / Plasticity
  Feature Space Decoupling](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2023/papers/Zhao_Rethinking_Gradient_Projection_Continual_Learning_Stability__Plasticity_Feature_Space_CVPR_2023_paper.pdf)

## Adaptative weights

Here, `lossTotal = weight1 * loss1 + weight2 * loss2`
Another strategy to try, but that will not grant you strict monotonicity of each loss term. Here are some examples in [Modulus documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/modulus/modulus-v2209/user_guide/theory/advanced_schemes.html#learning-rate-annealing):

- learning rate annealing
- SoftAdapt
- relobralo
- etc

## Levenberg-Marquardt optimizer

This optimizer is used to minimize a sum of squared terms of the form:
$$lossTotal = \sum_i f_i²(model_{parameters})$$, where each residuals/term $f_i$ of the sum is minimized.

In this case, the total loss would have the following form:
$$lossTotal = \sum_i r²_{1,i} + \sum_j r²_{2,j}$$ where $r_{2,j}$ is the j-th residuals of `loss2`.

Here are some implementations in TF of this optimizer:

- github: https://github.com/fabiodimarco/tf-levenberg-marquardt
- in tfg: https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/api_docs/python/tfg/math/optimizer/levenberg_marquardt